# Monitoring the cost of Snowpipe (in Snowflake)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

### (A Snowflake User asked the following in our legacy Q&A Forum)

Is there a way to put snowpipe under resource monitor? Or is there a similar way to monitor the cost of the snowpipe?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### (According to one of our Technical Account Managers on Snowflake's Professional Services Team)

It does not appear at this time to have that functionality. From the documentation:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/resource-monitors.html

"In addition, an account-level resource monitor does not control credit usage by the Snowflake-provided warehouses (used for Snowpipe, automatic reclustering, and materialized views); the monitor only controls the virtual warehouses created in your account."

and

"An account-level resource monitor only controls the virtual warehouses explicitly created in your account; it does not control credit usage by the Snowflake-provided warehouses (for Snowpipe, Automatic Clustering, and materialized views)."

You can monitor your credits however in the PIPE_USAGE_HISTORY table.

Information Schema

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/pipe_usage_history.html

Account Usage

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/pipe_usage_history.html

Using that information you could pause the PIPE with PIPE_EXECUTION_PAUSED

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/alter-pipe.html

Maybe a scheduled stored procedure to monitor and notify/pause at levels set in the stored procedure? I have not done this, but think it should work in theory. Hope that helps.

---

Interested to see if anyone else has any "outside of the box" ideas in addressing the above question... perhaps a method to employ as a work-around?